# How salesforce can suscribe to events happening in external system

Tags: apex, platform-event

No document, no example i am able to find to know without middleware how we can suscribe to external system. If we write schedule batch class to login and fetch events then how this becomes a event driven architecture/event?

Even though salesforce has introduced events, I have seen rarely in use in someone architecture for integration.

Comment: Take a look at [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration) and [Event-Driven Architecture](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/event-driven) architecture decision guides

Comment: The external system needs to support subscription for you to be able to subscribe to it. This is not a Salesforce thing if the external system isn't Salesforce.